# Selenium doesn't wait for page to reload after button click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to scrape sports results from a  [webpage](http://www.scoreboard.com/au/tennis/wta-singles/australian-open-2016/results/) that loads data with JavaScript. I have written a simple function to grab the html code and send it to beautiful soup and then parse the relevant parts (see below). In order to get all the results, I need selenium to click the 'show more results' button. Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly - the function only returns the results that were originally visible:

```
url="'http://www.flashscore.com/tennis/wta-singles/australian-open-2016/results/'"
def get_results(url):
    try:
        from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
        req = Request(url)
        s = urlopen(req,timeout=20).read()
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="tournament-page-results-more"]/tbody/tr/td/a""").click()
            time.sleep(5)
        except:
            print("No more results to show...")
        body=driver.find_element_by_id("fs-results")
        soup=BeautifulSoup(body.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "lxml")
        matches=[]
        rrows=soup.find_all("tr")
        for rrow in rrows:
            if rrow.attrs['class']!=['event_round']:
                matches.append(rrow)
    except:
        print("Webpage doesn't exist")
    return matches
```

The function should return a list of 150+ elements, but instead only returns 141. Any ideas on how to fix? It seems like the code continues running before the page has a chance to load the additional results?

Comment: Is it always 141? Are you sure the page actually loads 150+ items each time? You could wait until item n° 150 is displayed. ("//tr[150]" I suppose)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `time` module from the Python Standard Library.

You just have to insert `time.sleep(x)` after the code, which clicks the button. `x`is the number of seconds you want Selenium to wait.

If you want to read more about the `time` module and the `sleep()` function, I recommend you [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html) page.

Comment: I have considered this, but am looking for something cleaner. How long should x be? five secs? will this always be enough? I am hoping there is a way to check webpage status or something along those lines.

Comment: You could also check with JavaScript if the document is loaded or count the elements and check after a specific time if they got more.